# JS error in ie7,8 and 5?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, ietester

I am using IE Tester and this code is not working in IE5, IE7 and IE8,
Please give me a solution

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IE Tester</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function functions(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        </script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="btn1" onclick="javascript:functions('<?php echo "add_new";?>');"/>
        <input type="button" value="btn2" onclick="javascript:functions('a');"/>
        <input type="button" value="btn3" onclick="functions('a');"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is it not working? What are the symptoms?

Comment: @KarandeepSingh Can you show the rendered HTML?

Comment: @RobW: if I wrote 'document.write(data)' then its working but alert is nor working here.

Comment: @KarandeepSingh _HOW_ is it not working? Your title says you get an error, so, which error?

Comment: Why do you care about Explorer 5 ?

Comment: @MrLister: error is thatc ==> alert box not showing

Comment: @Sparky672 - the op probably doesn't care about IE5, but cares more that it works in IETester across all IE versions it supports which is 5.5 - 9.

Comment: I don't use IETester because you'll just never know for sure if you have a IE issue or an IETester issue.  I use the free [MS Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) and the [free Hard Drive images provided by MS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575) for testing websites in IE versions 6 through 9.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the following PHP output in IE8 and it works fine.  I'd say you may have found a bug in IETester.  But, you might want to remove the "javascript:" part just to see if that helps.  ***Edit:*** This [forum](http://www.my-debugbar.com/forum/t294-Javascript-Alerts.html) might help as well, it looks like the bug has been reported before.

```
<html>     
  <head>         
    <title>IE Tester</title>         
    <script type="text/javascript">             
      function functions(data){                 
        alert(data);             
      }         
    </script>             
  </head>     
  <body>         
    <input type="button" value="btn1" onclick="javascript:functions('add_new');"/>         
    <input type="button" value="btn2" onclick="javascript:functions('a');"/>         
    <input type="button" value="btn3" onclick="functions('a');"/>     
  </body> 
</html
```

> 

FYI... I used [CodePad](http://codepad.org/) to generate the PHP output, then tested with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript is correct, so if none of the buttons are working then the likely reason is that you have de-activated javascript in your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you escape the quotations in the input onclick event using backslash \"

```
<input type="button" value="btn1" onclick="javascript:functions('<?php echo \"add_new\";?>');"/>
```

Comment: the html parser will not parse the input field properly and just evaluate "javascript:functions('<?php echo "

Comment: But if it's a PHP page, the resulting HTML will be fine.